# Asp.net 2.0 Hide Default.aspx from Url

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have one issue with my site. I need to hide Default.aspx from Url. My web site project uses urlrewriter net and I tried using it to make this but no success.

I read lot of articles on net how to do this but nothings work.

Does this is only possible to set on IIS ?

I wont all ways to have www.test.com instead of www.test.com/default.aspx

Please for best solution ?

Comment: How about setting the default document to `default.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading tons of articles this is solution for my problem.. 
setting this javascript onto masterpage

```
var testremove = location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("default.aspx");
if (testremove != -1) {location.replace(location.href.substring(0,testremove))};
```

Comment: Won't this result in a lot of round trips to the server? I would have though @Brian_Rizo's suggestion would have been better.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using iis 7 or above, this might be a way of going about it.

> The Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 and above enables IIS administrators to create powerful customized rules to map request URLs to friendly URLs that are easier for users to remember and easier for search engines to find. You can use the URL Rewrite module to perform URL manipulation tasks.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

And heres a link to see the module in action.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module